# How to disable "Install Adobe Reader" prompt in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-reader

In Windows, i'm happy with Google Chrome's built-in PDF Reader plugin. Even, i use it as default PDF reader for Windows.

But for some PDF's, Chrome always prompts like "Parts of this PDF document could not be displayed. Install Adobe Reader?". I don't want to use Adobe Reader (or Adobe's PDF plugin) and i don't want to be annoyed everytime i open a PDF.

So, is there a way to stop these prompts? Under the hood setting or command line switch etc.?

*This question is relevant for Google Chrome 22 or lower versions. With the release of Google Chrome 23, [this issue is fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140474).*

Comment: You won't be able to get rid of the warning.  Just dismiss it when its displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some extensive searching, I believe that you can't get rid of the warning. I agree that it is annoying. The best that you can do is disable Chrome's built-in PDF viewer and use a different one.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I filed an issue about this [here's the link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140474)

Answer (score -2):

Try to disable `Chrome PDF Viewer` going to `about:plugins`. Then you can install official Adobe plugin that does the same function with full PDF support.

Comment: I don't want to use any Adobe thing. I'm happy with Chrome's PDF plugin except the prompt.